# Recursive solution of linear optimization with incrementally added dimensions and constraints

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, recursive-algorithms

I'm interested in understanding whether there is a nice recursive-type relationship between solutions of linear optimizations problems of lower and higher dimensions.

E.g., Fix $a,b,c,d,e,f\in \mathbb{R}$. Suppose I have the solution $(\hat{x}, \hat{y})$ to the  2D linear optimization problem of maximizing $ax+cy$ such that $bx+dy\ge 0, x,y\in  [0,1]$. How does this solution relate to the 3D solution $(x^*, y^*, z^*)$ of maximizing $ax+cy+ez$ such that $bx+dy+fz\ge 0, x,y,z\in  [0,1]$ ?

Given the 2D solution, is there an optimizing method (or closed form solution) that allows the 3D solution to be attained?

Any reference suggestions or  links would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: “The” solution might not exist.  It is easy to formulate problems that have infinitely many optimal solutions.  If you have an optimal BFS for the original problem it is easy to extend it to a BFS for the higher dimensional problem.  You can perform primal simplex iterations to get an optimal BFS for the new problem.  Is that the kind of answer your looking for?  If not, could you explain what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks @Brian Borchers. Yes,  indeed the solution need not be unique (sorry for the sloppy language). That answer is helpful but not quite what I'm looking for. 

Rather, suppose a solution to the 2D problem is (3/4,1). In the 3D problem, if  I know that $e>0,f=0$,  then  a solution to the 3D problem is (3/4,1,1). If $e>0, f>0$, then the solution to the 3D problem is  (q,1,1) for some $q\in (3/4,1]$. 

I am interested if a statements such  as "if $f/e>0$ is greater/smaller than $b/a$ we have $\hat{x}$ is greater/smaller than $x^*$" (using the notation from  my question statement).

Comment: You can explicitly compute the reduced cost for the newly added variable and determine ranges of values for which the old basis will still be optimal with the new variable nonbasic at 0 and at its upper bound of 1.    if the basis is no longer optimal, then you'll have to reoptimize.